# UIButton multiple events

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I'm working on a project that ask to do the following steps.

1. Displays a `UIButton` with an initial count of 0
2. Touching the `UIButton` first time increments the count
3. Touching the `UIButton` second time increment the count every 1 second

My code got stuck at step 3, if I touch the `UIButton` the second time, the count will keep incrementing by 1. I can never get into `[self performSelector:@selector(doDelay:) withObject:button afterDelay:1.0]`.

How can I add a counter to count how many times the user has clicked the `UIButton`?

Here is the code I have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    CGRect rect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    button.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
//Step (1)
    [button setTitle:@"Count = 0" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.window addSubview:button];
//Step (2)    
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(doButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//Step (3)
    [self performSelector:@selector(doDelay:) withObject:button afterDelay:1.0];

    return YES;    
}
-(void)doButton:(id)sender
{
    static int count;
    count++;
    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Count = %i", count];
    UIButton *b = sender;
    [b setTitle:s forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
-(void)doDelay:(id)object
{
    [self doButton:object];
    [self performSelector:@selector(doDelay:) withObject:object afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

Comment: You can't have multiple `action` targets; You need to have one target method and do different things in it based on the button count.  Also, it is highly unusual to add a button directly to the window and handle events in the app delegate.  You would normally use a UIViewController subclass.  XCode will set all of this up for you if you select "single view application" when you create a new project.

Comment: why can't you use NSTimer instead of performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:

Comment: what is your requirement Multiple action.....? or Step 3. Touching the UIButton second time increment the count every 1 second..... and again you are saying 
"the count will keep incrementing by 1. I can never get into [self performSelector:@selector(doDelay:) withObject:button afterDelay:1.0]."

Answer (score 0):

For multiple button actions you have to remove button target doButton and add other you wanna. For your case pass to doDelay method your count and add it to afterDelay:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int count; 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    CGRect rect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    button.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
//Step (1)
    count = 0;
    [self updateButton:button];
    [self.window addSubview:button];
//Step (2) and (3)   
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(doButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return YES;    
}

-(void)updateButton:(UIButton *)button {
      NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Count = %i", count];
      [button setTitle:s forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(void)doButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    count++;
    if(count == 1) {
      //Step(2)
      [self updateButton:button];
    } else if(count == 2){
       //Step (3)
      [self performSelector:@selector(doDelay:) withObject:button afterDelay:1.0];
    }
}
-(void)doDelay:(UIButton *)button
{
    count++;
    [self updateButton:button];
    [self performSelector:@selector(doDelay:) withObject:button afterDelay:1.0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove this line

```
[self performSelector:@selector(doDelay:) withObject:object afterDelay:1.0];
```

and Replace this two action in your code....

```
-(void)doButton:(id)sender
{
    static int count;
    count++;
    NSString *s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Count = %i", count];
    UIButton *b = sender;
    [b setTitle:s forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if (count == 2) {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                         target:self selector:@selector(doDelay:) userInfo:sender repeats:YES];

    }
}
-(void)doDelay:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [self doButton:timer.userInfo];
}
```